# How to find pairwise all combination in a Postgres hstore column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, hstore

I have a table in Postgres with an hstore column like:

```
"surface => concrete, ramp => yes, incline => up, highway => footway"
"surface => asphalt, lit => no, source => survey, incline => 12.6%, highway => footway"
"bicycle => yes, surface => asphalt, highway => footway, segregated => no"
```

Now I would like to analyse the keys among themselves. Therefore I want to know for the whole dataset how often the keys occur in combination pairwise.

The result should look something like this:

```
|      Key 1          |     Key 2        |       Count      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      surface        |    source        |         1        |
|      surface        |    highway       |         3        |
|      surface        |    incline       |         2        |
|      highway        |    bicycle       |         1        |
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `akeys()` to get all keys of the `hstore` column as an array, generate all distinct pairs of the arrays elements with `generate_subscripts()` and group the result by the pairs:

```sql
select akeys[i] as key1, akeys[j] as key2, count(*)
from my_table
cross join akeys(hstore_col)
cross join generate_subscripts(akeys, 1) as i
cross join generate_subscripts(akeys, 1) as j
where akeys[i] > akeys[j]
group by 1, 2
order by 1 desc, 2 desc
```

Test it in [db<>fidlle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/pl63OFU5)

Comment: Thanks this works very well, even with my larger database it is quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

Use hstore's `each()` to expand it out, then join and aggregate:

```
with expand as (
  select id, k, v
    from htab 
         cross join lateral each(hcol) as c(k, v)
), pairings as (
  select t1.id, t1.k as key1, t2.k as key2
    from expand t1
         join expand t2
            on t2.id = t1.id
           and t2.k < t1.k
)
select key1, key2, count(*)
  from pairings
 group by key1, key2
 order by key1 desc, key2 desc;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pccN7U21)